# editable picture and text in dashboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm developing a dashboard that end-users can edit specific web page by uploading different picture and editing text in the page. The similar ideas is [here](http://rocketway.net/themebuilder/template/?template=mason&purchase_code=5038837362728472).

I'd already done with web page design and I'm looking for suitable js library to make editable dashboard for end-users. Anyone has suggestions for that or if no current solution => how to implement these features? no idea about that ...

Very Thanks!

Comment: We don't really do software tool recommendations here on SO. Make Google you best friend. It will lead you to the variety of tools that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look on :

http://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js/

http://innovastudio.com/content-builder.aspx

http://etchjs.com/

http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/

http://createjs.org/

http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-wysiwyg-editor/

and use the one(s) that most suit you. In case you did not find the one that completely suits to your project then you can make additions (such as adding modal windows or css styling) to hte one(s) which is more preferable.
Hope this was helpfull.